# App registers in AAD and apps.dev.microsoft.com

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I've registred an app in apps.dev.microsoft.com using my Azure account. I would like to use the configuration that Azure brings, but the app isn't listed on App registrations in my Azure AD.

Why is so?

Answer (score 0):

The apps created in apps.dev.microsoft.com are not controlled by Azure AD, and can be created even using Microsoft account without Azure subscription / any users can login to the app.